# Problem with custom plugin using AJAX to pull info from php file

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I'm extremely frustrated over what I expected to be an easy task.

I have a wordpress plugin that I'm looking to do the following (with woocommerce) --

- Customer adds a product to cart.
- Javascript was added to footer on load using the plugin (wp_footer) to run a simple ajax request to `myfile.php` once this happens.
- I get the response from `myfile.php`, then i could manipulate that data as needed.

When i do this my normal way, i get a file not found, but i can access it directly.

I've done this many times in the past, without wordpress, with no issue. Now i'm seeing things about needing to use admin-ajax as some sort of intermediary?? compounding that, all examples have things about adding in add'l JS files, which I'm not looking to do. I just want the JS added to the footer to look at a php file, then use that php files content elsewhere.

I've stripped down my code below. It's not exactly my original intent, I just plan on moving the script in `myfile.php` to the `my_action` function. It returns a 400 error after many different attempts. can anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks

````php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); 
function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action'
        };
        jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
    </script> 
<?php }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
    echo "ok";
    wp_die();
}
?>
'''

This was my original code. Straightforward, I would very much like to know why something so simple doesn't work. Returned 404 a number of methods.

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_updated(  ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){ 
            $( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                alert('updated');
                $.ajax({
                    url : '<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-content/plugins/handle-multiple-items/return-items.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {},
                    success : function(data) {              
                        console.log(data); // 'data' used for additional things.
                    },
                    error : function(request,error)
                    {
                        alert('An error occurred.');
                    }
                });
                
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php }; 

add_action('wp_footer', 'action_woocommerce_cart_updated'); ?>'''
````

Comment: Have you considered a REST API endpoint? That would give you a pretty permalink and options to let WP itself check things like wether the user is logged in and sanitising parameters etc. It'll even give you human readable error messages, unlike the old `admin-ajax.php` API which just gives cryptic responses if you use it wrong. There's a good chance the plugins you're working with ( WooCommerce ) have already implemented REST API endpoints that do what you want to do that you can just make a request to

Comment: Also, you only hook into the `nopriv` logged out handler, not the logged in handler